# How to filter against URL with foreign key field in Django REST, overwriting get_queryset method correctly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to filter my queryset against an url with django REST but can't really get it to work.

I want to pass a string in the URL (a project name). According to this string, which is a foreign key, I want to filter my queryset (BuildingGroup).

I don't want to use query params but a url filter. I followed the docs but there is not so much on it on the site.

This is what I am trying:

```
class ListBuildingGroupProject(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = BuildingGroupSerializer
    filter_fields       = 'project'

    def get_queryset(self):

        project = self.kwargs['project']
        building_groups = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(project=project)
        result = building_groups.order_by('-creation_date')

        return result
```

The line `building_groups = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(project=project)
    throws me a KeyError for project.`

```
Here are my models. Note that BuildingGroup has one Project. A project can belong to many BuildingGroups. 

class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    project               = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
```

```
   class Project(models.Model):
       project_name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True, unique=True)
       start_date              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
       end_date                = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

and here my URL:

```
    path('project/<str:project_name>', ListBuildingGroupProject.as_view(), name='building-group-project'),
```

Help is so much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `building_groups = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(project__project_name=project)`?

Comment: @RaideR thanks for the hint, it still gives me the Key Error. I think ```self.kwargs['project']``` is not accessing the parameter I pass in the URL.... Or that I am using filters incorrectly in general maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your url, your argument is called `project_name`. This is what you should get from the kwargs. Beside, you want it to match the project.project_name:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    project_name = self.kwargs['project_name']
    building_groups = BuildingGroup.objects.filter(project__project_name=project_name)
    result = building_groups.order_by('-creation_date')

    return result
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend, works like a charm!! So in general I have to use the name of the model and then the field? Like model__fieldname?

Comment: This is because you span a relation. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships for more detail on the topic

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) about this.
It'll require to install [Django Filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html)

You just need to declare in some *rest_filters.py*

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import BuildingGroup
class BuildingGroupFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   class Meta:
       model = BuildingGroup
       fields = { 
           "project__name":["exact","icontains"],
           "project":["exact","in"]
       }
```

Then within your ViewSet declaration:
    [...]
    from .rest_filters import BuildingGroupFilter

```
class ListBuildingGroupProject(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=BuildingGroupSerializer
    filterset_class = BuildingGroupFilter
```

You can now enjoy a restfull behavior with:
`{path_to_your_endpoint}?project__name__icontains="Hello World"`
or `{path_to_your_endpoint}?project__=[Project Id List]`

To checkout how things works, filters are available in the browsable API.

Comment: thanks for the answer Julien. Sounds like a good option. I decided to stick with the simple overwrite of the queryset because it seemed simpler and without extra dependencies. But I might implement that in the future. Thanks a lot!